# Firefox dynamically generated link clicking

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have logic, what when users clicks "download" button, it makes http request to rest api, and then by response browser or starts download, or writes user a message what download cannot be started, code looks like this

```
if (file.is_active) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = filesUri + file.path;
    link.title = 'filedownload';
    link.setAttribute('download', file.body);
    link.click();
} else {
    // error message
}
```

and this code works perfectly in safari/chrome, but it doesn't in firefox, is there any possibilities to bypass this check?

Comment: 1: What is in file.body, 2: Any console errors?

Comment: use  e.preventDefault();

Comment: file.body is file name, but it doesn't change anything, this line can be removed

Answer (score 1):

Firefox probably prevents downloading without user interaction.

You should put your button inside *a* tag, set listener to button and before event delegates to link change *a* attributes to download correct file.